# Pyinstaller write method crash on executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

After create the executable file with pyinstaller, crash application in write method.
Anyone know how solved this problem?

MacOS Catalina 
Python 3.6

```
fw = open("/Users/user/Desktop/samplefolder/sample.csv", "wt")
fw.write("Hello")
fw.close()
```

Comment: Is there any error message? You can check it by opening the exe from command prompt

Comment: Ok wait please!

Comment: What is the error you get? Just a crash? That said, you probably can't write to the folder you're attempting.

Comment: Try using a full path to sample.csv.

Comment: I wrote full path on my code. Plz check edited.

Comment: does the code work BEFORE creating the executable?

Comment: @buran Before creating the executable, yes

Comment: @Everyone And now... I runned by terminal my application to check the error log, but nothing error. It works. But run from .app file, not working.

Comment: I hope one day can solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

#### please use the below code if you are trying to write data into a .csv file using python

```
import csv
with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Hello"])
```

Comment: how does this answer address OP question?

Comment: I didn't know that there it is!! I'll check it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This way worked fine. It's really Great.But Still don't know why write method always crash... only run with .app file.Your answer is useful. I added useful point.